# webpack require.ensure error with javascript

Tags: webpack

I am trying to follow this tutorial on webpack

http://blog.madewithlove.be/post/webpack-your-bags/

I was instructed to create an src/index.js with code below:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll('a').length) {
    require.ensure([], () => {
        const Button = require('./Components/Button');
        const button = new Button('google.com');

        button.render('a');
    });
}
```

When I run the webpack and then view the webpage, my chrome developer tools reports the following error in the console

```
Caught TypeError: Button is not a constructor
```

What's going on?  How do I fix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the answer.  I replaced

```
        const button = new Button('google.com');
```

with

```
        const button = new Button.default('google.com');
```

I don't understand why it works, but it does...I was just randomly inspecting object properties and trying different things and this seemed to fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

the `require.ensure` and `require` are **ES5** commonJS patterns, it looks like your `./Components/Button` module is most likely exporting using `export default` syntax of **ES6**, therefore:

`import Button from './Components/Button'` in **ES6** is the same as
`require('./Components/Button').default` in **ES5**

in the future instead of using `require.ensure` you will be able to use `System.import` in Webpack 2.0

https://webpack.github.io/docs/roadmap.html#2